# Converting .TIF Image to PNG via GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion

I have used this code line to convert my .TIF image to PNG :

> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.26.0>gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3
> -r cubic -of PNG "C:\Users\Cemre\Downloads\0309_0_aug_1.tif" "C:\Users\Cemre\Downloads\0309_0_aug_1.png"

This worked fine but it just gave me a grayscale image though it shows that it is 3 bands.
How can I have the rgb version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What color interpretation gdalinfo shows for the selected bands 1, 2, and 3?  Are they "undefined", or some color like here

```
Band 2 Block=12000x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
```

Gdal_translate copies the color interpretation from the source image but it can be overridden with the `-colorinterp` option https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-colorinterp. In your case the command would be

```
gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -r cubic -of PNG -colorinterpr red,green,blue "C:\Users\Cemre\Downloads\0309_0_aug_1.tif" "C:\Users\Cemre\Downloads\0309_0_aug_1.png"
```

Notice that png format does not support color interpretation and therefore this info is stored into .aux.xml sidecar file

```
... 
<PAMRasterBand band="2">
    <ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>
...
```

If a viewer is aware of the meaning of aux.xml files it can apply the correct color interpretation. One example of such viewers is QGIS.

Comment: I guess windows image viewer does not have this support that QGIS has, so it can't apply the correct color interpretation. I can see the colors in QGIS but not in a regular picture viewer. Thanks.